# PHP MVC: Registry class

Tags: php, model-view-controller, class, registry

Is there some crucial difference in writing the registry class in MVC with magic methods and writing the class with "regular" get and set methods?

For example, if I write the class with __get and __set I would access the registry objects through $registry->foo, and the other case would be $registry->getObject('foo'), or something like that, you understand me. I'm interested in the differences between these two, is something better or maybe depends on the particular situation or no difference?

Comment: Are you sure that this needs `mvc` tag? I do not see how this relates to MVC architecture. If it does, you should append some additional details, why the MVC context would be important ..

Comment: Well... because I implemented the registry pattern in an MVC architecture. I already wrote that the registry class is for MVC. I implemented it in order to create and store the objects for things such as database, url processing, templating, etc... I also store things such as project settings and stuff like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference. It's mostly language specific. Use of registry is same for all languages and it's up to you how you solve read/write problem on implementation level. Only important thing is correctness of implementation everything else depends on: a) project level coding conventions; b) your taste; c) language abilities.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP it makes almost no difference. While getters and setters strictly define class interface and allows you to put additional code such as data validation into them, magic methods may facilitate your work if there are many properties to operate with. But in heavy load magic is significantly slower.

If your class acts as an entity only, you may use magic. You might be also interested in [`Nette\Object`](http://api.nette.org/2.0/Nette.Object.html) approach.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your suggestion. I will surely take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

People tend not to access directly a public object but instead via its accessor, there is nothing difference at all, only using an accessor method is more preferable because it offers a better look for what is meant encapsulation and thus is a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Lets just ignore for a moment that registry is kinda an anti-pattern.

Use of `__set()` and `__get()` comes with a minor performance penalty. But that can be ignored.The real problem will become noticeable later.

What if you have to store something that requires additional computation before it is set or returned. For example, what if you are storing time. Lets say, outside `Registry` you are using time in a "pretty" format, but you are storing it in unix-time format. This would require to add a special exception go your magic getters & setters.

What if you store more then one such value. What if something changes and your application has to migrate from metric to imperial system.

As you add more and more conditions to the stored information, this all usually results in huge `switch` statements in `__get()` and `__set()`. Really bad design choice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why do you think that registry is an anti-pattern? Would you like to explain on this some more?

Comment: @Darko , depends on implementation details: all `Registry` structures violate [Law of Demeter](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LawOfDemeter). Also, a lot of people (does not apply in your example though) have tendency to build static registries. This then results in creation of global state and tight coupling.